# Three.js particle system as background forced behind other objects?

Tags: three.js, particle-system

I have a particle system that I am using to generate background stars - I have it tracking position with the camera but sometimes, the stars will render closer than the bodies which they are meant to be the background for.

Is there a way to force the particle system to always render behind the other meshes in my scene (almost as a background wallpaper - but moving with rotation)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easily.

- create a renderer with autoclear = false
- clear your render with renderer.clear();
- render your particle system as a separate scene
- clear the depth of the rendering with renderer.clear(false, true, false);
- then render all other objects.

And voila, you have a particle system that always stays behind the scene.

http://jsfiddle.net/vuQ9R/10/

Comment: Even easier. With just one scene, you can set `depthWrite` to `false` in the particles material and `particles.renderDepth = 0`: http://jsfiddle.net/vuQ9R/13/

Comment: yep I made it too damn hard again

Comment: Haha, I would have done it like this some months ago too. But you learn tips and tricks every day.